# Let's write some tag wiki entries

Tags: discussion, tagging, tagwiki

As of yesterday, hovering the mouse pointer over a tag will show (amongst other info) the tag wiki excerpt. This makes the tag wiki content more prominent on the site. Unfortunately, the tag wikis of most of our tags are empty.

Remember that you can now make tag wiki suggestions directly on the the wiki. If you do so, please remove the tag from this list afterwards.

Here is a list of tags from [the first tag page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags) that do not have a description (when directly editing a tag wiki page, please remove the tag from the list).

- [xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xetex) (has an entry, but is very short)
- [table-of-contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents) (excerpt, but no wiki)
- [vertical-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertical-alignment)
- [compiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiling)
- [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins)
- [numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numbering)
- [latex-general](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex-general) (excerpt, but no wiki)
- [layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout)
- [formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting)
- [color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color)
- [captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captions) (excerpt, but no wiki)
- [templates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templates)
- [programming](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming)
- [editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editors)
- [line-breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-breaking)
- [tools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools)
- [paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paragraph)
- [page-breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-breaking)
- [pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstricks)
- [indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentation)
- [conversion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion) (excerpt, but no wiki)
- [syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax)
- [size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size)
- [labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labels)
- [matrices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrices)
- [two-column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-column)
- [counters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counters)

Comment: I like that calling. I've already edited some tag wiki entries, for the most frequently chosen tags.

Comment: This is an excellent idea. Let's try and keep the list of "needs work" tags updated, so we don't duplicate effort...

Comment: I've added basic tag wikis for biblatex and sections.

Comment: When I click on the _Help us edit this wiki_ link, I get a 404. I guess this means I cannot edit tag wikis.

Comment: @TH. No that means, the link is wrong (it goes to meta, were the tag doesn't exist).

Comment: @Caramdir: Ah, I see.

Comment: I guess the idea here isn't as useful anymore, since everyone can edit tag wikis now.

Answer (score 3):

**{align}**

`align` is an environment in math packages that permits multiple related equations to be formatted vertically with a common reference point, usually at a sign of relation.

---

The `align` environment is provided by packages such as `amsmath` and `mathtools`.  The alignment reference point is indicated by `&`, which should be placed just before the sign of relation or operation in order to obtain proper spacing. The end of all lines except the last is indicated by `\\`.  The related environment `alignat` allows horizontal
space between equations on the smae line to be explicitly specified.  Both
`align` and `alignat` produce equation numbers; starred versions without numbering are
provided as well.

Sub-environments `aligned` and `alignedat` are building blocks to be used when the
aligned component is only part of a longer multi-line structure. The width of each
component is only as large as necessary, so that it can, for example, be set within
delimiters.

Use of these environments is described in the `amsmath` users guide, which on a TeX Live
system can be accessed by `texdoc amsmath`.

Comment: I copied this to the actual tag wiki.

Answer (score 2):

**[texlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texlive)**

This tag is used for questions relating to TeX Live, a widely used TeX distribution.

---

[TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/) is TeX distribution that is mostly used on Unix-related operating systems like [linux](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) and [osx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx). It is, however, also available for [windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) (where [miktex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miktex) is commonly used).

For questions concerning Mac TeX, which is a based on TeX Live, use the [mactex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mactex) tag.

*Copied to Tag Wiki on 2011-01-12.*

Answer (score 1):

**[best-practices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices)**

*Roughly modelled on [the best-practices tag from programmers.sx](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/best-practices/info)*

A "best practice" is a technique or approach that TeXnicians recognize as  giving better results than other approaches.

---

For example, it is widely accepted that there is value in separating commands that govern formatting from the document content — this is an example of a goal that is sometimes impractical to apply, and overall best practice provides guidance on how to manage the cases where it is not practicable.

For another example, when writing macros for packages or modules intended for use by others, it is a long-established best practice to use the `@` character for internal macro names, which do not conflict with macros in regular documents, so that users do not have to pay attention to the package internals.

Comment: @barbara: you can also suggest edits directly on the tag wiki page (this whole idea here became somewhat obsolete when SO decided to let everyone make suggestions to tag wikis directly)

Comment: @Caramdir: Wrong subthread!  But as you have raised the point, I don't know how the notification of tag wiki edits works: is it seen by all 5k+ rep. users?

Comment: It is seen by mods and 10k users and (i think) 5k users who happen to look at the tag page at the right moment.

Comment: Right subthread, as I was referring to her edit of your entry.

Comment: @Caramdir: Thanks and right.

Answer (score 0):

[listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings)

`listings` is a package that provides advanced features for typesetting computer code

---

The [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package extends LaTeX's `verbatim` features. A variety of syntax highlighting options are available.

For the unrelated concept of list structures, use the [lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists) tag or the tag corresponding to a specific list structure.